Evaluate hierarchical clustering with partial ground truth
I am performing hierarchical clustering, and I need to decide which agglomeration method to use.
While I don't have a ground truth, I know that some datapoints should be closer together: for example, measures that come from the same gene are expected to be mostly in the same clusters (but not always). Another example could be samples which may come from the same patient, but where we don't have a blocking design (so some patients have a single sample).
This is a case of external validation, but not one where we have a real ground truth or complete clustering to compare to (so Rand or F1 indexes aren't appropriate).
I was thinking of using an algorithm such as:


perform clustering with method ward
separate the n points in k clusters

count the number of times the same gene is in the same cluster, compute some "compactness index"
redo for k = 3 until k = n, sum the compactness for all ks


redo for method complete, average, etc...


Maybe another similar approach could be: for each pair of points with the same gene, compute some kind of co-phenetic distance along the tree; sum these distances for each pair of points.
I could try to implement these approaches myself, but I feel like there may be similar methods that already exist, that I just couldn't find.
I'm working in R, but interested in any standard method (although it would be great if there is an available implementation).

If you can construct a categorical variable, grouping your observations according to some knowledge, that will be a "ground truth" partition. You could create a series if such alternative ground truth partitions, each telling one side of the "vague" ground truth "story".

Whenever you have a pair if categorical variables, partitions - you can apply some external cluster validity measure. The overview of most of them: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/586470/3277

Thank you, I think I can get somewhere from this advice
