How to compare multiple point patterns of the same realm resulting from different clustering methods?
I have a dataset of 500 sampling points to which I apply multiple different clustering methods for categorization. How can I compare the resulting spatial point patterns of cluster group labels? I seek a single-number statistic that resumes spatial similarity, regardless of the actual group labels which often do not correspond between the different clustering (i.e., cluster A of clustering 1 does not necessarily correspond to cluster A of clustering 2).

Can this be relevant? https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/586470/3277
